# Try to figure out a good way to split English document into sentences in C#

Tags: regex, nlp

Is there a good way to split English document into sentences? I mean English document frequently includes Mr. Mrs. U.S.A, etc. It is difficult to separate them out. Do we need a special natural language library to accomplish this? I suspect that we need it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you need a complete understanding of English to do the job.

As a decent "almost" solution, you could use a dictionary of "things that end in period" and split on periods which do not immediately follow one of those tokens.

Comment: But of course, there are instances where an abbreviation also ends a sentence. "I need to talk to the Mrs." Or the "etc" in your question!

Answer (score 0):

If every sentence begins with a capital and ends with a period, then I would define a sentence as the above but contains >1 word and does not end with (common abbreviation list or regex [a-zA-Z].+)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***sentence detector*** provided by numerous NLP tools such as [OpenNLP](http://incubator.apache.org/opennlp/) or [Stanford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml). They can handle cases like Mr. Mrs. U.S.A, etc.

Both OpenNLP and Stanford CoreNLP are written in Java.
[SharpNLP](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/) is C# *(ported)* version of OpenNLP.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It looks like I do need a library to accomplish it.